# Azure Pipeline job for automatic pull request creation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm looking to add a job to one of our Azure pipelines that, when a change is checked into branch X, it will generate an Azure Devops pull request to merge branch X's most recent change into branch Y. The pipeline we're adding this job to is triggered by changes to branch X, so we should have info on that change. We are using YAML files for our pipeline configurations.

Some behaviours I'm looking for:

1. If no ADO PR merging X into Y currently exists:

   - Create one
   - Add the person who made the change to branch X as a reviewer of the PR
   - If the PR making the change to X has a linked work item, add that work item to the PR
2. If a new change is made to X while there's already an open PR merging X into Y, then:

   - Add the author of this new change as a reviewer to the "X -> Y" PR
   - Add any linked work items of the completed PR into the "X -> Y" PR

I found [this Create Pull Request](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest&targetId=f77d7bff-fef8-47d4-8c90-aa2b1c0ee245) task which looks like it can help me take care of step 1, but I still need help with step 2 and a few other details.

My questions are:

- How can I check if a pull request between X and Y already exists?
- How can I update that pull request if it does exist?
- What variables do I have access to in my pipeline to help me determine:

  - Who made the initial change to X?
  - If there was a pull request associated with the change made to X, what work items were linked to it?

If there's an easier way to do what I'm looking for, that would of course be helpful as well!

Comment: What you are trying to do seems rather out of the ordinary and requires a fair amount of effort to create the solution you have described.

Could you please explain the purpose as to what you are trying to accomplish, and perhaps we may be able to come up with an alternative solution?

Comment: @ScottRichards The goal is pretty much what is stated in the beginning, we need teammates to copy any changes made to branch X to branch Y ASAP. People often forgot to do this though, so we wanted to have their PR generated automatically as a reminder, and as a way of reducing a step in that process.

Comment: @ScottRichards We're also looking into ways to have this merge done automatically without generating a pull request, but doing this securily is tricky and requires review, and the functionality outlined above will still be necessary in case there are merge conflicts between the two branches.

Comment: Have you considered that if you need to keep these two branches constantly synchronized that you might have a process problem?

Comment: @DanielMann They are not constantly synchronized. Branch X is a production branch, branch Y is a development branch. We want to make sure all of the patches made to our production branch get down into our development branch immediately, but we only merge our development branch into our production branch when we're ready.

Comment: Currently Azure DevOps does not have this feature. You can explore the Azure DevOps REST API for pull requests. For example, use this API [Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&tabs=HTTP) to determine if a pull request between branchX and branchY already exists; use this API [Update Pull Request Reviewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/update-pull-request-reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to update a pull request to add reviewers, etc.

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT I see. That's too bad. If you know of any feature request trackers for this kind of thing, it'd be much appreciated so I could track this functionality

Comment: Hi @WalterSvenddal, please check the feature request link in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Azure DevOps does not have this feature. You can explore the Azure DevOps REST API for pull requests. For example, use this API [Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&tabs=HTTP) to determine if a pull request between branchX and branchY already exists; use this API [Update Pull Request Reviewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/update-pull-request-reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to update a pull request to add reviewers, etc.

You can request a feature for Azure DevOps [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion)  to track this functionality. Usually they prioritize feature requests with more votes.